# Problems transferring great amount of data to SD card of Android phone

Tags: usb, android

I have a HTC Desire *rooted* with *CyanogenMod 7* and a 16GB microSD card.
When I copy great amount of data from Ubuntu 10.04 64 bits to this phone via USB, the speed is low (*~1'2 MiB/seg*) and sometimes the system doesn't respond during copy process.
It's very difficult determine where is the problem. Any clue?

Comment: At launchpad there are various bug reports related to this for example: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/119325  Once I was able to fix this by installing  new (Debian) kernel (that wasn't patched by Ubuntu).

Comment: You are not alone. When writing to or reading from my 16GB micro SD card on my Android the read/write speed is slow. However, I have never experienced it stopping in between copies. It's always successful albeit slow as a turtle. One time, I was copying 5.7GB worth of data and it took several minutes (like 36min or more) just to finish writing to the micro SD card.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be an inherent problem of writing to a memory card connected to the computer via a mobile phone. I face the same issue with my Nokia. I recommend you to get a card reader, to get marginally faster transfers, because that is what I do.

Comment: But besides the slow, there is the serious problem of system doesn't respond from time to time while copying.